# Is there a way to queue function calls?

Tags: swift, swift4

For communication with backend during the checkout process I have the async functions:

*create()* : Creates the cart on backend. Called when user segues to the checkout page.

*update()* : Edits the cart on backend. Called when user edits the cart.

*confirm()* : Confirms purchase on backend. Called when user places the order.

*update()* is dependent on response from *create()*, *confirm()* is dependent on response from *create()*/*update()*

The user can call one function while another is unfinished e.g edits cart shortly after segue to checkout page. This causes problems due to the dependencies.

I have currently semi-solved it by using the bools *processing*, *shouldUpdate* and *shouldConfirm*.

**Is there a way to achieve by using a queue where the next function call waits until the previous has finished?**

```
var processing = false // Set true when a function is executing
var shouldUpdate = false // Set true when user edits cart
var shouldConfirm = false // Set true when user taps "Purchase"
var checkoutID = ""

func create() {
    processing = true
    APIClient.sharedClient.createShoppingCart() {
    (checkoutID, error) in
       ...
       processing = false // Finished with network call
       if shouldUpdate { // if edit was done while create() is running
           update()
           shouldUpdate = false
       }
       if shouldConfirm { // if user tapped "Purchase" while create() is running
           confirm()
       }
    }
}

func update() { // Called from view controller or create()
    if processing {return}
    processing = true
    APIClient.sharedClient.updateShoppingCart(forCheckoutID: checkoutID) {
    (error) in
       ...
       processing = false // Finished with network call
       if shouldConfirm { // if user tapped "Purchase" while update() is running
           confirm()
       }

    }
}

func confirm() { // Called from view controller or create()/update()
    if processing {return}
    APIClient.sharedClient.confirmPurchase(forCheckoutID: checkoutID) {
    (error) in
       ...
       /// Finish order process
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify the order of functions you need to call.

Comment: The functions are async functions with completion handlers that are called on user interaction (as described in the OP). The user can initiate calls quickly, causing the problems as described. Or initiate calls in a slow enough manner that allows for previous call to be finished - this doesn't cause a problem.
The challenge is that I can't know when a user decides to initiate calls or in what order.

Comment: You can call these three functions separately right?. Why you are calling the update() and confirm() function inside the cerate() function?
I mean, you need to call create() function,  when the user checkout the page. And then, when the user clicks on edit the cart, you need to call update() function. Like same as, when the user clicks on to confirm the order, you can call confirm() function.

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, yes. Right now I call them inside said functions to handle the case when a user calls for instance edit() while create() is unfinished.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use **PromiseKit** - Nice article [generally here](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/parallel-programming-with-swift-promises-740be1a260ed), wrapping [async here](https://hackernoon.com/promise-pattern-on-swift-with-promisekit-620efad7a5bd) - and [how to promises here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9208-getting-started-with-promisekit)

```swift
// your stack
var promises = [];

// add to your stack
promises.push(promise); // some promise func, see above links
promises.push(promise2);

// work the stack
when(fulfilled: promiseArray).then { results in
    // Do something
}.catch { error in
    // Handle error
}
```

Keywords for similar solutions: Promises, Deferred, Async Stacks.

---

or:
You could implement the following:

Have a pool, array of tupel: methodhandler and bool (=executed true)

create a func(1) runs all funcs from the array, in another wrapper function(2) that will set the tupels bool when it is executed.

func(1) will wait till the tupel is changed, and grab the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dispatch Group

```
let apiDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func asyncCall1() {
    apiDispatchGroup.enter()
    print("Entered")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
        /// After 3 Second it will notify main Queue
        print("Task 1 Performmed")
        /// Let's notify
        apiDispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    apiDispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        /// Perform task 2
        asyncCall2()
    }
}

func asyncCall2() {
    print("Task 2")
}
```